# Big Sur: An error occurred while installing the selected updates

Tags: macos, big-sur

I tried to update the macos from the 10.15.7 to the recently released Big Sur. Software Update has dowloaded the installation data and the following popup dialog appeared.

[image: Popup dialog with error]

I found in Console's system.log the following message, but I'm not sure if it's related to my problem.

```
Nov 12 22:58:02 coolomet com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SoftwareUpdateC.1617): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/SoftwareUpdateConfigData, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

I checked that the requested file exists in my system in the given location.

```
➜  Resources pwd
/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources
➜  Resources ls -l SoftwareUpdateConfigData
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  42192 22 zář 02:25 SoftwareUpdateConfigData
```

How can I download the Big Sur from the scratch again? I cannot find the location of downloaded installer. I don't see the usually downloaded installer in the `/Application` directory.

```
➜  Resources ls -l /Applications | grep -i install
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   96 12 lis 22:54 Install macOS Catalina.app
```

Comment: Just found that this issue is probably wide-spread: https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/12/macos-big-sur-download-issues/

Comment: I'm having the same issue, wanted to join you in solidarity. When I try to manually execute the binary, I end up with the same "file not found" issue

Answer (score 0):

Along with the comments to the post, this is still ongoing for some per Apple Support Twitter page.

https://twitter.com/AppleSupport/status/1327041964014002178

Apple is saying that the issue is resolved, but an issue still persists on my end.